# Failed to installed Android Studio

Tags: android

I failed to installed Android Studio on (Windows 10 x64 ). I tried several times and every time my installation process stacked at

```
m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/22.1.0/cardview-v7-22.1.0-javadoc.jar.sha1
```

and never go ahead. Please help why this happen ?

FYI: My Internet connection is very fast and there is no interruption during installation.

[image]

Comment: Try installing it on another partition or re-download the setup, the setup could be corrupted.

Comment: It installed but when I start the studio it start downloading it's components and then stacked

Comment: Is the window itself is "freezed" or window is responsive and progress bar is stuck at the same place? If the progress bar is stuck, give it some time to do it's tasks.

Comment: I have wait 3 hours and nothing happen